# change text color in adapter and fragment

Tags: android

Good day. I need to change text color in of list view with the switch of a button click. List view with custom adapter and custom layout. Text view in newsitemlist_layout.xml inflated with adapter normal it works fine but in fragment give error "Adaptor.setTextColor(int)' on a null object reference." The problem is that adapter is initialized in fragment and switch or button in main activity if I implement change text color in fragment it works but not in main activity. So now need on click in main activity and change text color in the adapter. Is there any way to do this. Please help.

Main activity.java

```
 NewsAdaptor adaptor;
   Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton)   
findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick ( View view ) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", 
Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, 
R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);


aSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
       @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
       @Override
       public void onCheckedChanged ( CompoundButton buttonView, 
boolean   isChecked ) {

               adaptor.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                adaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();
               } else {


                adaptor.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                adaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
       }
    });


public boolean onNavigationItemSelected ( MenuItem item ) {
    int id = item.getItemId();


    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        FeagmentA expressMain = new FeagmentA ();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager= getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.containerview,expressMain,expressMain.getTag())
                .commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
        Jungmain expressMain = new Jungmain();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager= getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.containerview,expressMain,expressMain.getTag())
                .commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    }
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
```

Fragment.java

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {


public FragmentA() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
ListView lvRss;
ArrayList<NewsItem> newsItemsList;
NewsAdaptor adapter;
public static FragmentA newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    FragmentA fragment = new FragmentA();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();

    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {

    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);

    lvRss = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.fragmentalistview);
    newsItemsList = new ArrayList <>();


    new n2().execute();
    return view;
}
private class n2 extends AsyncTask<Integer,Void,Intent> {
    @Override
    protected Intent doInBackground ( Integer... integers ) {
        try {
            Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/urdu/pakistan/rss.xml").ignoreHttpErrors(true).get();
            Elements itemElements = document.getElementsByTag("item");
            for (int i = 0; i < itemElements.size(); i++) {
                Element item = itemElements.get(i);
                NewsItem newsItem = new NewsItem();
                newsItem.setImagePath(item.child(5).getElementsByTag("media:thumbnail").first().attr("url"));
                newsItem.setDate(rem1(item.child(4).text()));
                newsItem.setTitle(item.child(0).text());
                newsItem.setLink(item.child(3).text());
                newsItemsList.add(newsItem);
                Collections.sort(newsItemsList, new Comparator<NewsItem>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare ( NewsItem o1, NewsItem o2 ) {
                        return o1.dateInMilliSec > o2.dateInMilliSec ? -1 :
                                o1.dateInMilliSec < o2.dateInMilliSec ? 1 : 0;
                    }
                });
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
       getActivity(). runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run () {

                adapter = new NewsAdaptor(getContext(), newsItemsList);
                lvRss.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);

}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
}
```

NewsAdapter.java

```
 public class NewsAdaptor extends BaseAdapter {
TextView tvtitle;
Context context;
private int color;



public NewsAdaptor ( Context context, ArrayList <NewsItem> newsList ) {
    this.context = context;
    this.newsList = newsList;
    this.color = Color.RED;
}

ArrayList <NewsItem> newsList;


@Override
public int getCount () {

    return newsList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem ( int position ) {

    return newsList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId ( int position ) {
    return 0;
}

@SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
@Override
public View getView ( int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent ) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = View.inflate(context, R.layout.newsitemlist_layout, null);

    }
    NewsItem currentNews = newsList.get(position);
    tvtitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1id);

    tvtitle.setText(currentNews.getTitle());
    tvtitle.setTextColor(color);
    return convertView;
}
public void setTextColor(int color) {
    this.color = color;
}
```

}

NewsItem.java

```
 public class NewsItem implements Serializable {

String title;

public String getTitle () {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle ( String title ) {
    this.title = title;
}


@Override
public String toString() {
    return title;
}
```

NewsItemlist.layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="150dp">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1id"
    android:layout_width="237dp"
    android:layout_height="83dp"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/pubDateid"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/pubDateid"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:text="News TITLE"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Comment: You cannot intialize adapter in Mainactivity class so you got null exception. From your scenario you need to create interface between activity & fragment in order to change something in fragment based on click event from main activity.

Comment: I know dear need interface tell me how

Comment: How did you load FragmentA from activity class?

Comment: Mohaideen Bahi in main activity I change code Please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this**

Add this code in MainActivity Click event:

```
Fragment frag = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.containerview); 

    if(frag instanceof FragmentA )
    {
        ((FragmentA ) frag).adapter.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        ((FragmentA ) frag).adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

**EDITED**

Change this line

```
 fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.containerview,expressMain,expressMain.getTag())
            .commit();
```

**To**

```
 fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.containerview,expressMain,"TAG_NAME").addToBackStack("TAG_NAME").commit();
```

Then find fragment from fragmentmanager in activity class like below:

```
Fragment frag = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("TAG_NAME");
```

Comment: Welcome glad to help